# Convert Mysql to Sequelize ORM

Tags: mysql, node.js, orm, sequelize.js

how to convert this sql to sequelize ORM?

```
SELECT * 
FROM `verses`
WHERE (surah_id, verse_latin_number) >= (112, 2) 
  AND (surah_id, verse_latin_number) <= (114, 3);
```

Comment: On which database's SQL implementation did that code work?

Answer (score 0):

Are "surah_id" and "verse_latin_number" 2 columns of the table "verses" ?

If yes:

```js
const db = require('...mydatabase.js')
const { Op } = require('sequelize')

db.Verses.findAll({
  where: {
    [Op.and]: [
      { surah_id: {[Op.gte]:112} },
      { surah_id: {[Op.lte]:114} },
      { verse_latin_number: {[Op.gte]:2} },
      { verse_latin_number: {[Op.gte]:3} }
    ]
  })
```